# Smooth scrolling does not work when clicking an anchor link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of hyperlinks on my page.that users will read when they visit the page.to make it attractive I can make the page scroll toward other section within the same page. i have added vanilla JavaScript to get smooth scroll but it seems not to work . I am wondering why isn't working at all.what is wrong with the code?

```js
      // Select all links with hashes
      const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
      // Add a click event listener to each link
      links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', event => {
          // Prevent default anchor behavior
          event.preventDefault();
          // Get the target element and its top offset
          const targetId = link.hash.slice(1);
          const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
          if (!targetElement) {
            console.error(`Unable to find element with id "${targetId}"`);
            return;
          }
          const targetOffset = targetElement.offsetTop;
          // Scroll smoothly to the target element
          window.scrollTo({
            top: targetOffset,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Smooth Scroll Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <section id="section1">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
         <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
        </p>
      </section>
      <section id="section2">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
        </p>
        </p>
      </section>
      <section id="section3">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
 <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
        </p>
           <p>
          Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
           Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna.
          Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
        </p>
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet does work for me.

Comment: @InSync  does not work for me what is wrong??

Comment: What browser and platform? Works for me in Chrome OSX

Comment: @InSync  i'm using chrome

Comment: Any console messages? Do you have some framework installed on the page you did not add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works but can be simplified to use delegation before you debug

Alternative for your scrollTo is scrollIntoView

```js
document.querySelector('nav').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let tgt = e.target.closest('li').querySelector('a'); // make sure the whole LI can be used
  if (!tgt) return;
  // Prevent default anchor behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get the target element
  const targetId = tgt.hash.slice(1);
  const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);
  if (!targetElement) {
    console.error(`Unable to find element with id "${targetId}"`);
    return;
  }
  targetElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="section1">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>
      Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
      text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
      condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="section2">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>
      Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
      text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
      condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
      <p>
        Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
        text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
        condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
      </p>
  </section>
  <section id="section3">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>
      Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
      text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
      condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
      <p>
        Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
        text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
        condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder
        text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae, condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting. Phasellus enim libero, blandit vel sapien vitae,
        condimentum ultricies magna. Lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used in design and typesetting.
      </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: still didn't work to me

Comment: If it did not work, why accept the answer? Again it works perfectly here at Stackoverflow, so perhaps you have something else running? Try running the code in an incognito window

Comment: the problem is that it loses the animation ..may be you can implement a cross-browser solution?

Comment: All the browsers I know and have access to will support the code I posted FX 110 and Safari 16.3 - Safari does scroll a little faster than Chrome and FX